# Show Django Model @property as a bool in model admin

Tags: python, django, admin

I have a model with a `property`, It returns boolean, I want to show it as icon in django model admin.

### models.py

```
class Foo(models.Model):
    bar = models.TextField("Title", null=True, blank=True)

    @property
    def is_new_bar(self):
        return bar == 'NEW'
```

### admin.py

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('bar', 'is_new_bar') # is_new_bar is shown as True/False text, I want this as bool icon of django.
```

[image: Boolean Icons]

Comment: Please check the indentation on your code excerpts...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add method to your modeladmin that will return property value and set that it will return boolean:

```
class FooAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
     list_display = ('bar', 'get_is_new_bar') 

     def get_is_new_bar(self, obj):
        return obj.is_new_bar
     get_is_new_bar.boolean = True
```

Comment: I would probably like this one, instead of touching models.py. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `property` use.

```
def is_new_bar(self):
    return bar == 'NEW'
is_new_bar.boolean = True
is_new_bar = property(is_new_bar)
```

Comment: awsome, Thanks. :)

Comment: Just checked doing `is_new_bar = property(is_new_bar)` takes away the on/off icon.

Comment: it's doesn't give you `checkbox` this way.