# Passing a model function to geojson serializer in GeoDjango

Tags: python, django, geojson, django-serializer

#### Problem description

Ok, I am trying to add a function defined inside a model (called Highway) to the HttpResponse of the model (Highway) after serializing with geojson serializer without success.

I'm trying to find a solution by going through the source code as no errors are passed and the property does not appear in the HttpResponse. I might however **be complicating** things and hopefully can get another eyes on this. I'm open to other suggestions, maybe to update the Highway each time a Location is added/modified.

The item appears correctly when passing it to the admin site and all other fields (not shown below) work as intended.

PS. I'm quite new to the whole Django system. Thank you!

Django version: 2.1

Relevant links:

1. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/contrib/gis/serializers/
2. https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/gis/serializers/geojson.py

---

#### Minified code

**geom.models.py**

```
class Highway(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)
    length = models.IntegerField("Length in meters")
    mline = models.MultiLineStringField("Geometry", srid=4326)

    def cameras_per_km(self):
        #THIS IS THE FUNCTION I AM TRYING TO SEND TO GEOJSON SERIALIZER
        count = self.location_set.filter(location__icontains="camera").count()
        return round(count/(self.length/1000),1)
    cameras_per_km.short_description = "Cameras/km"


class Location(models.Model):

    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    highway = models.ForeignKey(Highway, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    point = models.PointField()
```

**geom.admin.py** (when passing the func to list_display the item appears correclty in admin)

```
class HighwayAdmin(LeafletGeoAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'cameras_per_km')

admin.site.register(
    Highway, 
    HighwayAdmin, 
)
```

**geom.views.py** (this doesn't)

```
def geojson_highway_all(request):

    geojsonformat = serialize('geojson', 
          Highway.objects.all(),
          geometry_field='mline',
          fields = (
            'pk',
            'cameras_per_km'  # <-- I want this to show
          )
    )

    return HttpResponse(geojsonformat)
```

**geom.urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'geom'

urlpatterns = [
    path('highways.geojson', views.geojson_highway_all, name='highways.geojson'),
]
```

Comment: django's default serializers really aren't suitable for anything beyond dumping or loading fixture data.  this is one of the pain points for which django rest framework was created.  For more info on why you should use DRF, check out https://www.reddit.com/r/django/comments/3h9oj8/what_really_are_the_differences_between_django/cu5pzu9 for a breakdown on this and similar points.  Also, if you're spitting out json data and making a restful api, I would look at integrating DRF or tastypie into your project because it will make working in the backend _much_ easier

Comment: @Jason Thanks for the comment. Might be time to look into the REST framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update:** I (Anton vBR) have now rewritten this answer completely but think @ruddra deserves some credit. I am however **open for alternative solutions**. Hopefullly this answer can helps someone out in the future.

---

Create a new Serializer based on geojson serializer

**geom.views.py**

```
from django.contrib.gis.serializers.geojson import Serializer 

class CustomSerializer(Serializer):

    def end_object(self, obj):
        for field in self.selected_fields:
            if field == self.geometry_field or field == 'pk':
                continue
            elif field in self._current.keys():
                continue
            else:
                try:
                    self._current[field] = getattr(obj, field)()
                except AttributeError:
                    pass
        super(CustomSerializer, self).end_object(obj)

geojsonformat = CustomSerializer().serialize(
      Highway.objects.all(),
      geometry_field='mline',
      fields = (
        'pk',
        'cameras_per_km'
      )
```

Comment: add @property decorator on `cameras_per_km` and check again :)

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39190681/2696165 or add `readonly_fields = ('cameras_per_km',)` in `HighwayAdmin`

Comment: Sure, looks more elegant than mine.

Comment: Ok I think I am done. By adding `()` to getattr we can call the model functions right away. This is now only done if selected_fields have not been used. This also helps us to get around `@property`.

Comment: For me it is working only without () in the "try" and with "@property"

Comment: This works great. Would there be a way to change it so that it automatically serializes all fields without having to define them in `fields = (pk, ....)`